# TableVeiw set sortOrder in javafx so that table is sorted with application start

Tags: java, javafx-2, fxml, scenebuilder

I am new to javafx and trying to do something similar to [this code](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/fxml_tableview.fxml.html). It creates a tableview in which **firstNameCol** is sorted when application start as its sort order is set.

I need a code which is in java (**not in fxml**) which can set sortorder so that my column are sorted.

I do not need code like to initiallly sort my data and then add it to table as I need table to be sorted with addition of data.

I have some idea like I can do

```
ArrayList<TableColumn<person, ?>> sortOrder ;
table.getSortOrder().addAll(sortOrder);
```

but am not able to set sortOrder properly to get things done.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Go to the Oracel web site.  There you will find excellent tutorials on using the Tableview control.  There's even an explanation of how to set the sort order.  You should generally not come to SO if you are seeking beginning tutorials.  There are better sites for them, anyway,

Comment: can you provide me link to some tutorial which shows how to set sort order. This link shows it in fxml but I want java code for it.


Thanks

Comment: done by hit and trial
table.getSortOrder().addAll(firstNameCol");

where firstNameCol is the TableColumn